# Using Select By Attribute and Select By Location simultaneously?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, arcgis-10.2, performance

Is there an existing tool that would allow to select by attribute and location simultaneously (or near simultaneously) in ArcGIS 10.0+?

Assume the data is stored in a file geodatabase, but could be moved to personal geodatabase or shapefile.

I have always just used python to accomplish this behavior, but if there is a built in tool that might give me better performance it would be good to know. This is a fairly common task and it seems like there should be something to address this, and maybe I just haven't found it.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such inbuilt tool; But I'll like to be proved wrong, and learn that there is a tool which does this.

Comment: Can you provide an example where performing these operations sequentially yields different results (regardless of the order of performance)?

Comment: If you can use arcobjects then the ISpatialFilter also has a WhereClause. This allows for selection by attributes and location simultaneously. A different method could be to change the definition query for the layer then select by location.

Comment: @DanPatterson: The output doesn't change, but the time taken for the output definitely changes. Note: My experience has been with the ISpatialFilter, where not only can you give the where clause, but also indicate if you want the `Where clause` to be executed first, or whether you want the spatial query to run first.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with afalciano. 
You can create a model that combines the two tools, that could look like this:
[image: Selection Model]

It would give you a interface that offers both selection types:

[image: User Interface of Selection Model]

Don´t forget to set the **Selection type** of the second selection to `"SUBSET_SELECTION"`

This model could then be called from a python script importing the toolbox using `arcpy.ImportToolbox()` and calling the model as any other tool.

Comment: I'm agree with him too! :D Thanks for having illustrated my previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is not such tool, however you can quickly create it using the **[ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000001000000)** defining a model that links together the two selection tools. Once created this tool, it can be used in Python scripting and other models.