# Selecting Points by their Spatial Location to an Attribute of a Layer

Tags: select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I have a large point layer of addresses within a district. Each address point has a field called "Street External Key [SEK]" which is tied (meaning identical to) the corresponding "Street External Key [SEK]" field that I have in another layer, a street layer for the district.

The idea is to be able to associate each address to the street off of which it is accessed (ex. 111 Main Street will have a SEK value of 22222, which is the SEK value of the street that it is right next to).

However, some errors have popped up where an address was tied to a SEK of a street miles away.

How would I be able to perform a search to get all addresses where the SEK is from a street that is, say more than 250 ft away, which means its probably an error?

I essentially want to select all points that are 250 ft or greater from a street (which to my understanding is select by location), where the street is defined by an attribute [SEK] that both features have values for (hence the attribute qualifier i need in addition to the select by location).

I looked at this Q&A, but have been unable to make the connection to my situation:

[Using Select By Attribute and Select By Location simultaneously?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74745/how-to-select-by-attribute-and-select-by-location-simultaneously)

Comment: Not sure what system you're using, but a relational database with spatial data/functions such as PostGIS would be a good tool to use

Comment: That Q&A is about ArcGIS Desktop but you do not mention in your question whether that is the GIS software that you are using too.